# onclick="func()" or .click()?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering which one of the above methods is preferred or is the general guideline that you use $(elem).click() for simple things and < a onclick="func(1, 2, 3, 4);" > when you need to pass parameters to the script when the element is clicked? I've been trying to only use $(elem).click() to keep the code clean and simple, but when you have to pass more than one parameter it gets tricky and function call on onclick="" seems like a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

One of the main ideas behind jQuery is unobtrusive javascript (i.e. HTML and javascript are two great tastes that don't taste great together).  Using the jQuery object and selectors to attach the functions is what they would prefer you do.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(elem).click(function() {
    func(1,2,3,4);
});
```

That seems like what you want, no?

Comment: But if the passed parameters to the function are unique to each element and you may have hundreds of these elements, it gets trickier to do it this way, so that's why I was asking if in those cases you should use the onclick="func(1, 2, 3, 4)" method or should you stick with $(elem).click(). You could of course put all those parameters into url query string like foo=1&bar=2 and put that into href="" and in the $(elem).click() use $(this).href() to get the values, but is it more efficient to just do onclick="func()"?

Comment: well then you should use the html5 data attributes to set unique values associated with each relevant element: `<a data-param="1">link</a>`

Comment: If you have hundreds of these elements the most efficient way is using [event delegation][http://www.danwebb.net/2008/2/8/event-delegation-made-easy-in-jquery] instead of individual onclick handlers for each element.  To keep the JS less mixed in with your HTML, you could store the needed parameters in a Javascript data structure, with keys for each object being the element ID or similar.

Comment: Technically it is faster to do onclick="foo()", this is more performant. But you shouldn't do that unless you are seeing horrible performance issues and have tried everything else.

I like Ben's idea of event delegation + a JS array of information. Seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

If the parameters could be determined at the moment of the click, I would suggest
the binding method:

```
$('a').click(function(){ someFunc(this.val, 2, 3, 4); })
```

One case I could think of of doing it inline, is if you're building multiple links in a loop where params 1, 2, 3 or 4 are varying according to a backend variable or something:

```
<% for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { %>
    <a onclick="someFunc(1,<%= i %>,3,4"></a>
<% } %>
```

Personally, I always try to bind to the event in a $(document).ready() callback.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use $(elem).click()  to keep my HTML javascript-free, I consider it cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the `click()` as well, if you have additional parameters that you want to pass to the function, add them to any of the object's attributes, I usually use `rel` like this:

```
<a href="#" class="link" rel="parameter1, parameter2, etc">Link</a>
```

in the script you can do this:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
 var parameters = $(this).attr('rel').split(',');
 // Do something
 return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to a function when you use jQuery:

```
$(".selector").click(function() { func(1,"2", someVar); });
```

I prefer to always use jQuery for my event handling. I don't like putting any behavior in my HTML, even with `onclick` and related events.

Also, if you programmatically click something using `$(".selector").click()` and you have a handler attached using both `onclick` and jQuery, it will call the jQuery handler first, then the handler set using the attribute. But if you click with your mouse, it's the other way around. That might be unexpected, and end up giving you headaches down the road.